# How can I make applications on OSX open new windows in the same space when opening a file from Finder?

Tags: macos, applications, finder, window-manager, spaces

OSX 10.8. Pretty simple. Right now when I open a file through Finder, if the filetype is set to be open by application Y, oftentimes OSX finds a space that has an open window of Y, and sends the file into that window in that space. What I want though is, when I open the file, I want a new window for that file, and in the same space.

Per [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9500/how-to-make-chrome-open-a-new-window-for-external-links), I know that there is a workaround explicitly for Chrome, which is great; ditto [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28210/how-can-i-open-a-finder-window-in-desktop-without-switching-to-another-one) for Finder. But I want this setting to be system-wide. E.g. I want to open a new txt document through finder and have MacVim open a new window with the file in my current space (as it would if it were launching for the first time) rather than locating an open window in a separate space and pulling the file into a tab in that window.

Note, I do have my settings set so that switching to an application does not switch to a space with an open window for that application, which works correctly, but when the application launch takes place through a file opening rather than via the cmd-tab switcher, it still does the find-an-open-window-even-if-in-another-space thing.

Note again, there are two issues here--

1. I don't like that it switches spaces
2. I don't like that it opens the file in an existing window rather than in a new window

--and I don't see how you can solve one without solving the other; but it'd be great if either or both could be solved.

Comment: What kind of applications are you using? Apple's document based applications open a new window when you double click a document in finder, they never reuse the window of an already open document.

Comment: This is a pretty natural request. Most users want to open a new window exactly where they are already working. If one is looking at a given organised space this usually is not an error but where one wants to work right now.

Comment: @rsanchezsaez In fairness not Apple-authored apps, e.g. Chrome, MacVim, etc. But I've observed a similarly frustrating behavior with the Finder, in which certain ways of instigating the opening of a folder that I have open in another space takes me to the displayed folder in the other space, rather than opening a new Finder window in the current space to display the folder. (I can't right now remember exactly what causes that to happen, but I'll post if/when I do remember. It happened just yesterday and prompted me to offer the bounty but I neglected to note the details of the event.)

Comment: @Philip Thanks for the clarification. I do not readily know of any way of achieving what you need. A good venue for exploration could be third party OS X windows managers like Divvy or similar. Maybe one of them offers this particular feature?

Comment: This is really a nightmare if you work on different applications grouped on space by Story your are working on, grooming on, create a POC and so on, can't understand why they don't fix it!!!

Answer (score 3):

Does setting the assign to Desktop:none; work for you.

You can do this from the Applications Dock menu.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately no. All the aforementioned applications are already assigned as such.

Answer (score 0):

To open a new window of an app in the current Space without triggering Spaces switch, right-click on the app in Dock - "New Window".

This approach works for most apps, however it won't work for some apps (triggering annoying Spaces switch). Here is the last resort:

In short, it opens a new window of app without (triggering) switching Spaces. How:

in the Space that you're working on and wish to have a new window of some app that already has other windows open in other Spaces, open Terminal.app (if necessary, set Terminal.app Keep in Dock and right-click on Terminal.app - "New Window") , run `open -n /Applications/Appname.app`

eg. `open -n /Applications/Vivaldi.app` A new window of the app will open in the current Space, as there wil be no annoying Spaces switch, your workflow in the current Space is not interrupted.

Reference: [Assign Application Windows to Different Spaces/Desktops](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105463/assign-application-windows-to-different-spaces-desktops)

Answer (score -1):

Disable the option under System Prefs -> Mission Control -> When switch to an application, switch to a space with open windows for this application

for some application this will not work, because some apps like TextMate open new documents in a new tab, but I’m pretty sure these apps have own options to prevent this!

Comment: Question explicitly states that that option is already set.

Answer (score -1):

I think I finally got a fix, for Microsoft Word (and presumably other Office apps too): Make sure you have a Word window open in all workspaces... of course, you can make the window really, really tiny and pushed away into a corner.

This also helps with the jump to another workspace with an open window when you close "the last" (actually useful) window on a workspace. This is on Mavericks.

A fully minimised (docked) window doesn't seem to do the job, though.